# SQLite Concat and JOIN of records

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a problem with proper DB query handling in my app and to be honest I don't know what I should do more to make it work.

My DB looks like this

```
BooksTable
-_id
-title
-author

RentsBookTable
-_id
-userId
-bookId
-date

UsersTable
-_id
-name

GenresTable
-_id
-name

BooksGenresTable
-bookId
-genreId
```

Everything from my DB I want to display inside a `ListView`.

I am taking everything with this clause:

```
BooksTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RentsBookTable ON(RentsBookTable.bookId=BooksTable._id)   
LEFT OUTER JOIN UsersTable ON(RentsBookTable._id=UsersTable._id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN BooksGenresTable ON(BooksGenreTable.bookId=BooksTable._id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN GenresTable ON(GenresTable._id=BooksGenresTable.genreId)
```

I want each row display title of book, the user name who rented it and the genres separated by comma.

Everything except the last part - concatenating and separating with comma of genres I am doing now correctly with displayed clause. Now books with more genres are duplicated. I've been trying

```
"GROUP_CONCAT(" + GebresTable.name + ",', ') AS " + "genresConcat"
```

Unfortunately I am unable to achieve my goal. With this concat I am always getting only one record with all genres concatenated and displayed.

Can someone please tell me how I can achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this, to show only genres that are different:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genre) AS genre
```

You will also need to group the genre with `GROUP BY` after the where clause to show all the records that match.

Comment: Ok, now it is concated correctly, but only one record is shown - the last one added. So I have almost this same as earlier with my concat.

Comment: did you use 'group by'?

Comment: I think it would be `GROUP BY BooksGenreTable.bookId`

Comment: I've used both sugested group by and none worked correctly. The outcome is this same.

Comment: It should work, maybe if you post your full `SELECT` statement, we can see what's going on.

Comment: Ok, it wokrs. I just checked my query and it came out that group by condition was in wrong place. Thank you